# WinForms Graphics Drawing

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I am trying to plot shapes in C# in a WinForms application using Graphics GDI library. Ideally, I'd like to plot them the same way I do in a web app using SVG.

I am given an array of points. Under SVG, I build the path like the one below and it renders correctly.

```
<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

I have tried (DrawLines, DrawLine) and none seemed to render properly. Also, I gave .DrawPath a shot but I didn't get better results.

```
using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath()) 
{ 
    color = new AESColor(this.GetBleedThroughValue(color), color.R, color.G, color.B); 
     using (Pen pen = CreatePen(color, AESLineStyle.Solid, width)) 
     { 
         Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points.ToPointFArray()); 
     }
}
```

Comment: can you post a screen shot of the expected results and the what you are getting?

Comment: Either find a .NET SVG library or learn the [path syntax here](https://css-tricks.com/svg-path-syntax-illustrated-guide/) or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp)

Comment: I understand but i was hoping to find an easy way to translate line commands to GDI+ methods.

Comment: Well, each of the path commands is in itself easy to convert to GDI+ but you still need to parse it.. Your example has a Move to, 2 LineTo and a Close Path command. These would make up an array of 3 points you would use to do a GraphicsPath.AddLines and one GraphicsPath.CloseFigure call.

Comment: _I have tried.. i gave .DrawPath a shot_ Show the code

Comment: ```
using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
      {

        color = new AESColor(this.GetBleedThroughValue(color), color.R, color.G, color.B);
        using (Pen pen = CreatePen(color, AESLineStyle.Solid, width))
        {
          Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points.ToPointFArray());
        }
      }
```

That is the one that i was trying as a simulation of it.

Comment: Well, a path in SVG is fiiled unless you write fill=transparent, afaik. Other than that it should work. So to fill it use AddPolygon and a FillPath with a Brush when it is complete. - [Another tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)